# replace nil values with zero in hash map

Tags: clojure, hashmap, null

I have a hash map in clojure which contains some nil values.  I am trying to group the data and sum the values, this gives me a null pointer due to the nil values.  Can someone please advise on how I can iterate through the hash map and replace all nil values with integer 0?

```
(def data [{:MEDAL "SILVER" :EMEA 1 :NA nil :ASPAC 3}
       {:MEDAL "GOLD" :EMEA 1 :NA 2 :ASPAC 3}
       {:MEDAL "GOLD" :EMEA nil :NA 2 :ASPAC nil}
       {:MEDAL "BRONZE" :EMEA nil :NA 2 :ASPAC 3}
       {:MEDAL "SILVER" :EMEA 1 :NA 2 :ASPAC 3}
       {:MEDAL "GOLD" :EMEA 1 :NA nil :ASPAC nil}
       {:MEDAL "BRONZE" :EMEA 1 :NA 2 :ASPAC 3}])
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(map (fn [m]
       (into {} 
         (map (fn [[k v]]
              [k (if (nil? v) 0 v)]) m)))
     data)
=> ({:EMEA 1, :NA 0, :MEDAL "SILVER", :ASPAC 3} 
    {:EMEA 1, :NA 2, :MEDAL "GOLD", :ASPAC 3} 
    {:EMEA 0, :NA 2, :MEDAL "GOLD", :ASPAC 0} 
    {:EMEA 0, :NA 2, :MEDAL "BRONZE", :ASPAC 3} 
    {:EMEA 1, :NA 2, :MEDAL "SILVER", :ASPAC 3} 
    {:EMEA 1, :NA 0, :MEDAL "GOLD", :ASPAC 0}
    {:EMEA 1, :NA 2, :MEDAL "BRONZE", :ASPAC 3})
```

Comment: Edited to `(if (nil? v) 0 v)` instead of `(or v 0)` because `(or false 0)` returns 0.

Comment: @ToBeReplaced your edit was rejected for some reason by the time I saw it - so I copied it instead, because it's obviously more correct.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than replace the nil values with zeros, you might consider just working with them by using `keep`.  For example:

```
(apply + (keep :NA data))
; 10
(apply + (keep (fn [m] (when (= (:MEDAL m) "SILVER") (:EMEA m))) data))
; 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `fnil`.

```
(->> data
  (apply merge-with conj (zipmap [:EMEA :NA :MEDAL :ASPAC] (repeat [])))
  (reduce-kv #(assoc %1 %2 (reduce (fnil + 0 0) 0 %3)) {}))
```

*Obviously :MEDAL needs other treatment.*

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to group the data by :MEDAL and then add EMEA, ASPAC etc., right?

```
;; Helper function
(defn batch-hashmaps
  "Applies operation on values of keys in maps. filterf filters valid values.
Example: (batch-hashmaps + [:b :c] number? {:a 30, :b 50, :c :cheese} {:b 30, :c 40})
=> {:b 80, :c 40}"
  [operation keys filterf & maps]
  (apply conj {} 
          (for [key keys]
            [key (apply operation (filter filterf (map #(key %) maps)))])))

(for [medal (set (map #(:MEDAL %) data))]
  (assoc (apply (partial batch-hashmaps + [:EMEA :NA :ASPAC] number?) (filter #(= medal (:MEDAL %)) data) ) :MEDAL medal))
```

This should be the desired result:

```
({:MEDAL "GOLD", :EMEA 2, :NA 4, :ASPAC 3}
{:MEDAL "SILVER", :EMEA 2, :NA 2, :ASPAC 6}
{:MEDAL "BRONZE", :EMEA 1, :NA 4, :ASPAC 6})
```

Answer (score 0):

And here is another quick and dirty thing.

```
(defn sum-medal
[medal data]
(assoc (apply (partial merge-with (fn [& [_ _ :as vals]] (apply + (filter number? vals)))) (filter #(= (:MEDAL %) medal) data)) :MEDAL medal))
```